# Is it possible to specify various types?

Tags: go

I just want to know if the feature described in title exists. I know that `interface{}` accepts any type but I want to use a bit more strictly like `var intOrString (int | string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing a feature known as "sum types". Unfortunately, Go doesn't currently support sum types, although there is [an open proposal to add such support](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19412).